# WordPress: Subquery with table join

Tags: mysql, wordpress

A query sorts posts by pageviews - this works perfectly. But I need to join **wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id** too. Like this:

```
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ='2'
```

the code:

```
$qstr = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, 
    (select postid, sum(pageviews) pageviews 
    from $pageviews_table 
    group by postid) pv
    WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wposts.ID = pv.postid
    ORDER BY pv.pageviews DESC
    LIMIT 10
 ";
```

I tried this:

```
$qstr = "
    SELECT wposts.*, wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, 
    (select postid, sum(pageviews) pageviews 
     from $pageviews_table 
     group by postid) pv
    WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 

    INNER JOIN
             wp_term_taxonomy
             AND xxxx // dont know
    WHERE    wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = '13'

    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wposts.ID = pv.postid
    ORDER BY pv.pageviews DESC
    LIMIT 10
 ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using join? Won't this work for you:

```
$qstr = "
SELECT wposts.*, wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, 
(select postid, sum(pageviews) pageviews 
 from $pageviews_table 
 group by postid) pv, wp_term_taxonomy
WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND    wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = '13'
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
AND wposts.ID = pv.postid
ORDER BY pv.pageviews DESC
LIMIT 10 ";
```